# Inverting a dictionary of <key : list of values> pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on this code that takes dictorainary that maps pages numbers to words on that pages and inverts it so it creates a new ordered dictionary mapping each unique word to all the pages that word occurs on

e.g the inpout:

```
words_on_page = {1: ['hi', 'there', 'fred'], 2: ['there', 'we', 'go'], 3: ['fred', 'was', 'there']}
```

.....should be returned as:

```
{'hi':[1], 'fred':[1, 3], 'there': [1, 2, 3], 'we' :[2], 'go': [2], 'was': [3]}
```

my solution so far inverts the dictionary but it makes it so the key is every word on that page mapping to the page number. I need to some how split the words in the the key and map them to a list of all pages they occur on

```
def make_index(words_on_page):
"""returnings inverse dictionarty mapping from a word (key) to an 
ordered list of pages on which that word appears"""   

inverted = {}

for page, word in words_on_page.items():        

    word = str(word)

    if word in inverted:

        inverted[word].append(page)

    else:

        inverted[word] = [page]

return inverted
```

Comment: I think I have figured it out, i just needed to add another iteration to itterate over all the words on the word list like: for page, words in words_on_page.items():        
        
        
       
        for word in words:""

Answer (score 1):

I answered the solution with the following (just needed to add another iteration)

```
for page, words in words_on_page.items():        
    for word in words:
        if word in inverted:          
            inverted[word].append(page)
        else:                
            inverted[word] = [page]

return inverted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `if` check using `dict.setdefault`:

```
o = dict()
for k, v in words_on_page.items():
     for i in v:
        o.setdefault(i, []).append(k)        

print(o)
{'fred': [1, 3],
 'go': [2],
 'hi': [1],
 'there': [1, 2, 3],
 'was': [3],
 'we': [2]}
```

---

You could also use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

o =  defaultdict(list)
for k, v in words_on_page.items():
     o.update({y : o[y] + [x] for x, y in zip([k] * len(v), v)})

print(dict(o))
{'fred': [1, 3],
 'go': [2],
 'hi': [1],
 'there': [1, 2, 3],
 'was': [3],
 'we': [2]}
```

Comment: I like the first one, easy and simple. But you will not get it into a single line like my pandas solution. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a pandas "one-liner" solution:

```
import pandas as pd

words_on_page = {1: ['hi', 'there', 'fred'], 
                 2: ['there', 'we', 'go'], 3: ['fred', 'was', 'there']}

def make_index(words_on_page):
    return pd.DataFrame(words_on_page.items(), columns=["page", "word"]) \
            .set_index("page")["word"].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index() \
            .drop("level_1",1).groupby(0)["page"].unique().apply(list).to_dict()

print make_index(words_on_page)
```

returns

```
{'we': [2], 'there': [1, 2, 3], 'fred': [1, 3], 'hi': [1], 'go': [2], 'was': [3]}
```

Comment: I’d count the import statement as a separate line, so your solution’s two lines as well. ;-)

Comment: Yep that's fair. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain
words_on_page = {1: ['hi', 'there', 'fred'], 2: ['there', 'we', 'go'], 3: ['fred', 'was', 'there']}
final_dict = {i:[a for a, b in words_on_page.items() if i in b] for i in chain.from_iterable(words_on_page.values())}
```

Output:

```
{'we': [2], 'there': [1, 2, 3], 'fred': [1, 3], 'hi': [1], 'go': [2], 'was': [3]}
```